# how to choose the last column as the range in QueryTable (Excel Macro)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import multiple tables next to each other using the QueryTable.Add

how do I choose the last column automatically in the range:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www....html", Destination _
    :=Range(??????)) <---- Here
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/11/09/find-last-column-in-an-excel-sheet-vbavb-net/

Comment: and how to I define it in the Range?  Range(lCol + "1") ?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,LCol)` Assuming that you want to paste it in row 1

Comment: You  might want to post an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;http://www....html", Destination _
:=ActiveSheet.Cells(X,LCol))
```

X marks the row